# Core Dumped While Multiplying Iteratively

Tags: c++

I am trying to do something very simple. I have a class for functions, and a class for polynomials derived from the function class.  In the polynomial, I am overloading the *= operator.  But, when I invoke this operator, the program dumps the core and crashes.

```
Polynomial& Polynomial::operator*= (double c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        a[i] = a[i] * c;
return *this;
}
```

The polynomial class holds the coefficients in array a. The index of a directly relates to the power of x for that particular coefficient.  Function main hands us the constant c, which we then multiply each coefficient by.

The prototype for the function is part of an assignment, or I would change it.  I'm assuming there's something I'm doing wrong with respect to the return type.  Any help is appreciated.

I am willing to provide more code if requested.

Comment: What is the declaration of `a` and how is it initialized?

Comment: a is a pointer and then dynamically allocated array of doubles. I'll look through the whole source, but it shouldn't be possible to pass a to that function without a being populated.

Comment: Consider whether `Polynomial` correctly implements the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Answer (score 4):

The return type is fine, I'm guessing the problem is `i <= degree` instead of `i < degree`. Arrays in C++ are 0-based.

EDIT: or perhaps you want to keep that as `<=` for consistency with the polynomial, in which case you need to allocate `degree+1` items for your array.

Comment: Rather, the allocation of whatever `a` points to is probably off. A degree-n polynomial has n + 1 terms, so the loop bounds are OK.